# How to add fonts in Libreoffice

Tags: fonts, linux-mint, libreoffice-writer, truetype-fonts

I run Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon and added several fonts through Software Manager, for specific example we will say the ttf-mscorefonts-installer package, but after installing the package successfully theyvli do not show up in Libreoffice Writer's font list.

Is there something else I need to do so that I can use the fonts in Libreoffice?

Answer (score 1):

If you have already installed the required fonts, then you need to update fonts cache.

In terminal, run the following command.

**If the font was installed for a particular user only.**

`fc-cache -fv`

**If the font was installed system wide.**

`sudo fc-cache -fv`

And then applications using fonts should recognize the newly installed ones.

---

Other way is to simply reboot or re-login after logging out.

Comment: I am no expert on Mint, but shouldn’t the software manager run that automatically?

Comment: It is not run automatically after install. The user can also restart or simply relogin to also do the same.